# how to redirect with post data from api using php curl?

Tags: php, angularjs, restful-url, php-curl

Actually i have been doing forgot authentication part using angularjs and restfullapis.i sent the key to the lost user mail for getting reset password panel. The user click on the verification url from mail(  http://workless/services/user/reset_pwd_confirm?verification_id=72e03c6aa3268cd37067243945ac69aa&user_id=5) the following apis calling.

```
    private function reset_pwd_confirm(){
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $verification_id = $this->_request['verification_id']; 
        $user_id = $this->_request['user_id']; 
        if(!empty($verification_id) && !empty($user_id) && $user_id > 0){
            $tm=time()-86400;
            $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user_pwd_reset WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' AND act_key='".$verification_id."' AND time > ".$tm."";
            $get_user = $this->db->get_row($query);                
            if($this->db->num_rows == 1){
                $curl = curl_init('http://localhost:3000/#/reset');
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user_id='.$user_id);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

                curl_exec($curl);               
            }else{
                $success = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "key and user are not match.");
                $this->response($this->json($success),404);
            }
        }else{
            $success = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Invaild verification or user id.");
            $this->response($this->json($success),404);
        }

    }
```

here i need to move the angular page called as http://localhost:3000/#/reset with post user_id, for this purpose i used curl as i mentioned above But it return error as **"Cannot POST /"**.
what was the problem?? please tell me.
i thought problem is request post from http get method,is it?
please give me the solutions...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670975/cannot-post-curl-to-nodejs-socket-io# and also post your api code so we can see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly than what you want to achieve is this:

User clicks a link in email (that is GET request), and it should trigger another POST request. Right?
I would be surprised if that was achievable via server-side redirect. You can workaround it on client via javascript.

but: Do you really need a POST request for it?
You already have a `verification_id` in the url. So when user clicks it, server can reset password or redirect user to "password reset form" and invalidate the `verification_id`. So `verification_id` can be used max 1 time.

would that be ok?

But if you REALLY need to perform that POST request, here is how.
Once user clicks that link, it will lead him to custom web page with something like this

html:

```
 <body onload="onLoad()">
  <form style="display:none" method="POST" action="some_url" id="myform">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="your_user_id">     
  </form>
 </body>
```

javascript:

```
 function onLoad() {
   var form = document.getElementById('myform');
   form.submit();
 }
```

Comment: why i need post request for http://localhost:3000/#/reset is i need to further append password with that user id and send the post request to reset password. that is why i'm trying to send post user_id data with that url.

Comment: i don't care to protect here user_id via post, i just send user_id as a post type for grabbing the user_id data in reset api because we can only send as post type data in reset api because of the password data.

Comment: private function reset_pwd(){
    if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
         $this->response('',406);
            }
          $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
          if(!empty($data['user_id'])){
              $user_pwd = $data['user_pwd'];
             $user_id = $data['user_id'];
            if(!empty($user_pwd)){                                                                                        
           $query = "UPDATE user SET password = '".$data['user_pwd']."'                    WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'";}}} /*this is my reset api